# Windows XP user name changed to USERNAME.COMPUTERNAME, now account is back to defaults

Tags: windows, windows-xp, user-profiles

I'm helping a friend with their Lenovo laptop running WinXP, SP3.   We had done some updates, ran Microsoft Security Essentials, and cleaned off something called arcaadewebfirefox.dll that I thought wasn't too terrible.  later that evening they rebooted and all desktop icons were gone, firefox was back to default profile, etc.  at the same they they received a couple calls from those scammers posing as microsoft and offering to fix the computer. I didn't think it was related but they are convinced the computer was hacked.

I've determined all the current problems are due to the fact that they are logging into a different user profile called USERNAME.COMPUTERNAME, where before everything was just under USERNAME.

For example, the desktop icons being used are at:

C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME.COMPUTERNAME\Desktop

instead of

C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Desktop

where I see all their previous icons where they should be, but not being accessed.

Similarly, the Firefox profile being used is here:

C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME.COMPUTERNAME\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\qkqvn5s1.default

instead of:

C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\sjdi38dj.default

How could this have happened, and what is recommended to get things back the way they were? Thanks!

Comment: The best way would be to create a new user, transfer the user file and firefox profile, then delete the previous user's profile directory.  I would actually just install Windows XP since the installation clearly has been made corrupt in some manner.

Answer (score 1):

Classic case of a corrupted profile. Many ways it could have happened. If you don't want to delete the profile reg key, you can try changing the `ProfilePath` Value of the

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Profile List\<SID of User>
```

Key back to the original folder, but be forewarned that in my experience this rarely works. Instead it's best to delete the entire SID, backup/delete the profile folders, and reboot the machine. When the user logs back on they'll get a fresh profile, and you can manually copy the data that's needed back to the 'new' profile folder.

Comment: So it appears they already do have a fresh profile, the one named 'USERNAME.COMPUTERNAME' -- is this a standard Windows convention that would have created this automatically?  Can I just copy the files into this one and be on my way?

Comment: yep, what happens is when the default profile folder already exists, it will create one with that name, and if that one exists it will create USERNAME.COMPUTERNAME2 & USERNAME.COMPUTERNAME3 etc. For some reason Windows thought the old folder was corrupted and gave you a new one. You can indeed copy the files into that folder if you don't care about the name. After all, a rose is still a rose.

Comment: thank you for the info.  I searched the Application and System event logs and didn't see anything...I would think if Windows was creating a new profile folder it would log it somewhere.  Do you know if this is logged.  I have a rough idea when it happened but didn't see anything.

Comment: I don't know about xp, but vista+ may log an entry along the lines of 'user profile service crashed' or similar, that's one indicator. It really depends on the nature of *why* it created a new profile to being with.