# On Windows 10 filesystem, what does user "UserName.LAPTOP-HBM2T2FA" mean?

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, user-accounts

I have a client in Australia.  On her Windows 10 system, she has the following users:

```
Default.migrated
fletc
Jane Doe
Jane Doe.LAPTOP-HBM2T2FA
Public
```

She logs into "Jane Doe".  There doesn't seem to be another user account for this second listed user.

When setting an optional file path in our software's preferences, that paths for her documents folder looks like:

```
C:\Users\Jane Doe.LAPTOP-HBM2T2FA\Documents
```

But when our software is trying to do a creation of a temporary file, it gets confused by the period in the user name.  That is probably OUR bug.

I was going to rename her user -- but I wanted to make sure this isn't some magical Window 10 syntax for some special feature, and 2) why her account would log into "Jane Doe.LAPTOP-HBM2T2FA" instead of "Jane Doe".

NOTE: "Jane Doe.LAPTOP-HBM2T2FA" has all her files.  "Jane Doe" has no files at all -- just the standard default folders.

Comment: The name of the profile indicates it's a local account and NO longer connected to a MS account

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound --  But how would it get that way in the first place?  Is this connected to OneDrive?  Why are there TWO profiles for "Jane Doe"?

Comment: My guess it was the connected profile, then it was disconnected, which created a new profile and in order to avoid a name conflict the machine was appended to the profile directory

Comment: @Ramhound so the real question is: how can that profile be renamed to NOT have the period and all that nonsense after the period?

Comment: Create a new user, then take ownership of the profile, and use that user instead

Comment: Related: [Windows XP user name changed to USERNAME.COMPUTERNAME, now account is back to defaults](https://superuser.com/q/622787/376602)